# Cloning android source code repo into a different directory

Tags: android

I followed instructions at http://source.android.com/source/download.html to build android source code on Mac OS X. Created case-sensitive image of size 8.5 GB and gave make for 'full-eng' target in lunch command, After sometime got this error complaining about insufficient disk space :

```
prebuilt/darwin-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-ar: out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebcore_intermediates/libwebcore.a: No space left on device
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebcore_intermediates/libwebcore.a] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebcore_intermediates/libwebcore.a'
```

Is 8.5GB not sufficient to build, instructions say 8Gig is enough.Did i miss something.?

Now I want to create another case-sensitive image of size say 12GB and build it, can simple copy of files from 8.5GB volume to 12GB volume work? Or is there any special command (git clone or something.. sorry noob to git) to copy the entire repo so that all git projects will copy safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the content safely with a simple copy. Nothing special linked to git. Make sure however that you copy the hidden .repo directory in your project root.